# Valores da função retornando undefined em Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, tipagem

```
var const1 = function (a,b,c,d){
return  (a*b+c-a)/d; {



const1(10, 2, 2, 10, 2);
console.log('a = ' + const1.a);
console.log('b = ' + const1.b);
console.log('c = ' + const1.c);
console.log('d = ' + const1.d);
```

Por que os valores mostrados através do `console.log` são retornados como `undefined` e não como os valores que estão armazenados na variáveis.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente, acontecerá assim que fizer a aceitação).

Answer (score 5):

Eles estão `undefined` porque eles não existem. Você está tentando acessar um objeto que em tese deveria ter esses membros, mas o que você tem é um objeto com um valor numérico único sem membros. Por alguma razão você acha que uma função é um objeto e ela não é, e neste caso tão pouco retorna um objeto.

Este código não faz o menor sentido. Sua função retorna **um** valor calculado e pode usá-lo, assim:

```js
function calculo(a, b, c, d) {
    return (a * b + c - a) / d;
}

console.log('a = ' + calculo(10, 2, 2, 10, 2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Calculator.js).

Se o que deseja é retornar 4 operações diferentes, teria que retornar um objeto ou *array* com os resultados que deseja, porém neste caso teria que definir o que são essas 4 operações para colocar cada resultado em um membro, aí poderia escrever o código acessando do jeito que deseja, o que me parece um pouco esquisito, mas seria algo assim:

```js
function calculo(a, b) {
return { adicao : a + b, subtracao : a - b, multiplicacao : a * b, divisao : a / b, };
}

var resultados = calculo(10, 2, 2, 10, 2);
console.log('adicao = ' + resultados.adicao);
console.log('subtracao = ' + resultados.subtracao);
console.log('multiplicacao = ' + resultados.multiplicacao);
console.log('divisao = ' + resultados.divisao);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Calculator2.js).

Por último pode ser que queria criar variáveis e não usar literais (não temos como saber sem a pergunta dar detalhes):

```js
function calculo(a, b, c, d) {
    return (a * b + c - a) / d;
}

var a = 10;
var b = 2;
var c = 2;
var d = 10;
var e = 2;
console.log('a = ' + a);
console.log('b = ' + b);
console.log('c = ' + c);
console.log('d = ' + d);
console.log('resultado = ' + calculo(a, b, c, d, e));
//note que a variável e não é usado em lugar algum, mesmo no original isso é um erro conceitual ainda que não dê erro
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Calculator3.js).

Na verdade pode ser várias outras coisas que queria fazer.

O fato de não dar nomes significativos no código ajuda você a não entender o que está fazendo e mais ainda para outras pessoas entenderem o que é sua necessidade. Ajuda menos o fato da pergunta não descrever o que quer, apenas diz o que está  errado. Desenvolver software é em primeiro lugar conceituar corretamente o que está fazendo, o código é consequência disso.

Answer (score 3):

`const1` não tem a definição de `a`, `b`, `c` ou `d`. `const1` é uma `function` que tem como retorno (`number`) o resultado de uma equação (`(a*b+c-a)/d`), no caso `const1(10, 2, 2, 10, 2);` retorna como valor `1.2`.

Um exemplo de como atribuir a `const1` as a definições de `a`, `b`, `c` ou `d`:

```
var const1 = function (a,b,c,d){
    return  {a,b,c,d, resultado: (a*b+c-a)/d}; 
}
var result = const1(10, 2, 2, 10, 2);
```

Assim `result` tem como valor: `{a: 10, b: 2, c: 2, d: 10, resultado: 1.2}`

```
console.log('a = ' + result.a); // a = 10
console.log('b = ' + result.b); // b = 2
console.log('c = ' + result.c); // c = 2
console.log('d = ' + result.d); // d = 10
console.log('resultado = ' + result.resultado); // resultado = 1.2
```